# Repopulate nl2br saved content inside textarea without <br> tags?

Tags: php, nl2br

When a user save a text from a textarea:

```
bfajsdb fkjasdfasjkdfasdfasdf asdf asdf sdf

asdfasdfasdfasdf asd asdf asdf 

sdfasdfasdf
```

from a textarea using nl2br_except_pre function in codeignter it saves it in the database like :

```
bfajsdb fkjasdfasjkdfasdfasdf asdf asdf sdf
<br>
asdfasdfasdfasdf asd asdf asdf 
<br>
sdfasdfasdf
```

It is nice for output in div or p tags. or in html output in general.

However, when repoopulating inside textarea again it shows the 
 tags, which is ugly and confuse the user.

How can I sanitize the output before repopulating the saved value from database so it looks in the textarea like this:

```
bfajsdb fkjasdfasjkdfasdfasdf asdf asdf sdf

asdfasdfasdfasdf asd asdf asdf 

sdfasdfasdf
```

and not like this:

```
bfajsdb fkjasdfasjkdfasdfasdf asdf asdf sdf
<br>
asdfasdfasdfasdf asd asdf asdf 
<br>
sdfasdfasdf
```

Comment: Then don't store HTML in your database :)

Comment: I need because I use it inside other html stuff on my page. I need a way fow to sanitize or change the output e.g. $row->textarea_content to remove br tags but to make the new lines correctly.

Comment: Then you apply nl2br() at rendering time :)

Comment: like: nl2br($row->textarea_content);   ? I will try

Comment: not doing anything nl2br($row->textarea_content);

Comment: I seriously doubt it doesn't do anything; unless it shows nothing, different problem altogether :)

Comment: What you are suggesting is doing it before saving, then it works, but I need opposite function like raina77ow suggested strip_tags()

Comment: No, what I meant is that you can just store the input that comes from the textarea without applying nl2br(), i.e. no HTML in your database. Then at rendering time you apply nl2br() to create HTML, except for the textarea contents. Btw, hope you're also escaping your output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the crude answer will be 'just use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)':

```
$raw_textarea = 'bfajsdb fkjasdfasjkdfasdfasdf asdf asdf sdf
<br>
asdfasdfasdfasdf asd asdf asdf 
<br>
sdfasdfasdf';

$clean_textarea = strip_tags($raw_textarea);
echo $clean_textarea;
```

But, in fact, there's much more to that: perhaps you need to worry about *sanitizing* your output, not just cleaning out irrelevant tags. I suggest reading [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090080/php-markdown-xss-sanitizer) on that topic.

Comment: Wow, seems to work and so simple, thanks. In my case only br tags are allowed, so no bold text, lists etc.

Answer (score 4):

Don't save nl2br() data in your database; you should aim to store data rather than html in your db.

Apply nl2br() to your database value upon rendering in your view where necessary. Textarea fields wouldn't need the nl2br() treatment btw.

Of course you should also apply htmlspecialchars() before nl2br() when you output it.

Answer (score 0):

Try nl2br php function

It will make your desired output.

Yes, this is right. If you are using nl2br function while displaying the data, it will work.

Comment: Yes, this is right. If you are using nl2br function while displaying the data, it will work.