# Not allowing javascript links in markdown

Tags: php, regex, xss, markdown

The primary XSS vulnerability in (PHP) markdown *after disallowing HTML* tags seems to be that it allows links like this:

```
[foo](javascript:alert('xss'))
```

which will turn into

```
<a href="javascript:alert('xss')">foo</a>
```

and the same applies for `<img src="">`.

I'm currently developing a very basic Q&A section on a site, and I use markdown for the questions and the answers. I can quite confidently say that the only legitimate use of links on this site will be `http://` or `https://` links.

If I modified the regex markdown uses to process links and allowed only urls beginning with the characters `http`, would that prevent XSS attacks?

P.S. This isn't part of my current question, but I would be much obliged if some kind soul showed me how to modify the frustratingly complex regex in question.

**EDIT:** I have already read [PHP Markdown XSS Sanitizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090080/php-markdown-xss-sanitizer) and the only reason I'm asking this question is because I'm considering an alternate approach. My question is not '*How to sanitize markdown output to prevent XSS*' but rather, '*Will this approach prevent XSS attacks*'? As such, it is not a duplicate, it is an alternative. Also, doesn't the fact that this question received upvotes show that there are at least some people who are wondering the same thing I am even though the earlier question exists?

Comment: I would say take a look at [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV What about encoded urls?

Comment: I don't know how exactly markdown works, but htmlentities will convert this `<a href="javascript:alert('xss')">foo</a>` to this `&lt;a href=&quot;javascript:alert('xss')&quot;&gt;foo&lt;/a&gt;`.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV I misunderstood last time, sorry. The problem with `htmlentities` is that it won't allow legitimate links through. I don't have a problem with normal `http://www.google.com` kind of links.

Comment: Ah (facepalm) you're right ...

Comment: Can you provide the regex or is it too big ?

Comment: It's a multipart process. I'll try and figure out what's actually going on and then provide the regex if possible.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV there are 3 functions, a total of around 3000 characters, so yeah, I think it would too much.

Comment: What you could do is the following, use a HTML parser to get all the links and maybe `<script>` tags, remove the script tags, and loop through all the `<a>` and check the `href` if it's only a link with http/https/ftp.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30312/discussion-between-vivek-ghaisas-and-hamza-dzcyberdev)

Comment: look at the related questions. The most popular answer seems to be to pass the result of the Markdown parser to HtmlPurifier.

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós I've read that question, and am searching for alternate solutions, such as the one I proposed above.