# How can I convert markdown to html (should i use an existing script)?

Tags: php, html, markdown

What is the best way to convert from markdown to html. Should i write my own script of use something already out there?

Are there any existing markdown converters you can recommend? that are lightweight and easy to install.

n.b. I am using php.

Comment: What do you mean convert plain text to markdown? Markdown is written in plain text.

Comment: Plain text would be identical in markdown, it only becomes markdown when you include the specific character sequences that are defined by markdown. Not sure what you are trying to achieve or if you really mean *plain* text.

Comment: sorry got myself mixed up there, meant markdown to html

Comment: First result in google for [markdown php](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/) seems pretty nice (and John Gruber from Daring Fireball [recommends it](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)).

Comment: Why should you want to write your own converter, if there is an existing one?

Comment: i had no idea, only recently actually heard about markdown, new territory for me.

Comment: You should have a look at [Parsedown](http://parsedown.org). It is fast, consistent and easy to use.

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós Actually, the first result in Google for 'Markdown converter PHP' is this question ...

Answer (score 9):

Check these PHP Libraries:

- [Mark Down Extra](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/)
- [Mark Down OO](https://devhub.io/repos/maxtsepkov-markdown-oo-php) ([GitHub](https://github.com/maxtsepkov/markdown-oo-php): Doesn't exist anymore, than I checked)
- [Parsedown](https://parsedown.org/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/erusev/parsedown))
- [PHP Markdown](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown))
- [cebe/markdown](http://markdown.cebe.cc/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/cebe/markdown))

Answer (score 7):

I think you should try something opensource first, then if the existing solutions don't fit your needs either try modifying them or rolling your own.

Parsedown looks rather promising:
http://parsedown.org/