# Markdown Files to HTML

Tags: php, html, markdown

Is there a PHP script to convert Markdown files to HTML?

I'd like to create a flat-file CMS that converts markdown files (in a content folder) to static HTML files that can be served on a website.

Comment: It's not THAT hard to find https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown/

Comment: provide us with what you've done so far?

Comment: -1 Writing the same question [into Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Is+there+a+PHP+script+to+convert+Markdown+files+to+HTML%3F) or [searching StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498794/how-can-i-convert-markdown-to-html-should-i-use-an-existing-script) would have given you the answer.

Comment: I think you are looking for https://github.com/robotamer/robotamer.github.com

Comment: what is wrong with this question? this is the exact question I had and this page google ranked #2 on my google search. I come to stackoverflow in preference any random google hit. Thank you user1505209 for asking the question. I am sorry the other stackoverflow users have been so rude to you.

Answer (score 8):

You might want to use a search engine before asking your question next time. You can take a look at [PHP-markdown](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/). If you're looking for a more complete solution (i.e. a full-fledged static site generator) take a look at [Phrozn](http://www.phrozn.info/en/).

Comment: Letrol - my google brought me here ;-)

Comment: Phrozn is now at https://github.com/Pawka/phrozn (but is now longer developed).